# Loop through Registry Python

Tags: python, windows, loops, registry

I am trying to write a small application that checks each value in the Windows Registry for valid file paths, provided it is a REG_SZ. I need to be able to loop through all of the keys and subkeys reading each value as I go. I looked in to _winreg, but couldn't find any clear examples for this task. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_winreg.OpenKey` to open a given registry key.
`_winreg.EnumKey` to enumerate the sub-keys of a given registry key.

And you have the `_winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and friends key constants.

What else do you need?

Comment: I knew that module existed and the options it provides. The structure of the keys are different, some may have only one level, other maybe 20. How would I use these to just loop through everything?

Comment: @Eli, yes.. thank you. But, I am needing some examples of how to do this. Is it as simple as recursing through files on a HDD?

Comment: @Zachary: yes, you have to write a function that recursively visits an entry and its sub-entries

Comment: @Eli, would you be able to write an example or provide some links to useful resources? I have tred Googling, but can't find anyting on recursive registry looping in Python.

Comment: @Zachary: placed here (http://paste.pocoo.org/show/392558/) some sample code I found in my archives for grepping through the registry. Study it and modify for your needs

Comment: What if I have to collect all the keys, subkeys and their values iterating over all the constants like, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG, HKEY_CURRENT_USER etc... ? Also, the link you have given @Eli, is not available...